# Vb.net - Display each network adapter, enabled or disabled

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, wmi

I'm trying to display the network adapters on the computer running this application.
For that I want to be able to display all network adapters, no matter which status they have.
Then I want to be able to enable and disable the adapters by pushing a button.

I've tried using `System.Net.NetworkInformation`, but it seems as though it only contains the one that's active.

```
' NETWORK ADAPTERS

' Create label
Dim LabelNetworkAdapter As New Label
Dim old As Padding = LabelNetworkAdapter.Margin
LabelNetworkAdapter.Margin = New Padding(old.Left, 8, old.Right, old.Bottom)

' CreateButton
Dim BtnConnectButton As New Button
BtnConnectButton.Height = 23
BtnConnectButton.Width = 60

For Each nic As NetworkInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

    Dim strText As String = nic.Description.ToString
    TableLayoutPanel_Nettverkskort.Controls.Add(LabelNetworkAdapter)
    LabelNetworkAdapter.Text = strText

    TableLayoutPanel_Nettverkskort.Controls.Add(BtnConnectButton)
    BtnConnectButton.Text = "Koble fra"

    Exit For

Next
```

Comment: That's what disabling an interface means, apps can't see it anymore.  Use WMI Code Creator to play with WMI queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible. When you disable a network interface, the operating system hides it from applications. Which makes sense, since you can't actually *use* it. The only way you're going to see it is in the shell's "My Network Places" folder (or whatever they've decided to call it now).

[This bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94408/networkinterface-getallnetworkinterfaces-misses-some-nics) on MSDN seems to aptly describe your problem. It was closed as "by design".

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx) even explains that the return value is:

> A NetworkInterface array that contains objects that describe the **available** network interfaces, or an empty array if no interfaces are detected.